# How to create multiple Jdbctemplate beans, pointing to different Mysql databases, in runtime?

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, spring-jdbc, jdbctemplate

I have a requirement to create a SAAS-based version of my project: when a new client registers, a new database for that particular client will be created; and in my spring boot code, a new JdbcTemplate bean for that client needs to be registered in runtime.

The creation of database part has been taken care of, but I need to know if there is a way to create a new custom Jdbctemplate bean on runtime.

I already have an idea of adding database prefix for all the queries, but I want to know it there is any other feasible option.

Comment: a dynamci JdbcTemplate will also demand dynamic DataSource which in turn will demand dynamic database credentials. Can you confirm if you already have database credentials discoverable at runtime for each new client? I'll be able to share a solution outline accordingly.

Comment: In our SAAS model, whenever a new client is registered, the DBs would be created using the scripts. So, we would have a master table to map the client ID and DB name. So The client ID would be sent as a parameter to all the APIs, based on that clientID, dynamically the JDBCTemplate needs to be created with the DB of respective clientID.

Comment: did you got any solution ?

Comment: @Avnish I do have same kind of requirement, and in runtime, i do have all the credentials. can you pls help me here?

Comment: @Ganesh, you can refer to this article for the same. https://careydevelopment.us/2019/01/18/how-to-configure-multiple-data-sources-spring-boot/
This can be implemented using  AbstractRoutingDataSource.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have figured out new database credentials already, following outline will give you a JdbcTemplate for each client. All relevant data-points are mentioned as comments in following code.

```
/**
 * uses a REQUEST scope with proxyMode as TARGET_CLASS to ensure wiring in spring context works
 * as it should for each and every request while caching created templates for full reuse.
 */
@Component
@Scope(value = WebApplicationContext.SCOPE_REQUEST, proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
public class TemplateResolver {
    @Autowired
    private TemplateCache cache;

    /**
     * You can inject current request OR any other bean for that matter here.
     * Assuming you are using Spring authenticaiotn object to get access to
     * current clientId. Adjust accordingly for your own use case
     */
    @Autowired
    private Authentication authentication;

    public JdbcTemplate getTemplate() {
        // TODO - extract this clientId from authenticaiton or any other means as appropriate
        Strnig clientId = null /* write your logic here */;
        return cache.getTemplate(clientId);
    }

}

/**
 * Caches created JdbcTemplate beans for further loockup and reuse as needed
 */
@Component
public class TemplateCache {
    private Map<String, JdbcTemplate> templates = new HashMap<String, JdbcTemplate>();

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext appContext;

    public JdbcTemplate getTemplate(String clientId) {
        if (templates.contains(clientId))
            return templates.get(clientId);
        return buildTemplate(clientId);
    }

    /**
     * This is a synchronized method to ensure concurrent requests DO NOT end
     * up creating multiple JdbcTempate objects.
     */
    private JdbcTemplate buildTemplate(String id) {
        // double check to ensure it's not already created by any other
        // concurrent request which finished its execution just now
        if (templates.contains(clientId))
            return templates.get(clientId);
        templates.put(clientId, appContext.getBean(JdbcTemplate.class, id));
        return templates.get(clientId);
    }
}

/**
 * uses a REQUEST scope with proxyMode as TARGET_CLASS to ensure wiring in spring context works
 * as it should for each and every request while caching created templates for full reuse.
 */
@Component
@Scope(value = WebApplicationContext.SCOPE_REQUEST, proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
public class TemplateResolver {
    @Autowired
    private TemplateCache cache;

    /**
     * You can inject current request OR any other bean for that matter here.
     * Assuming you are using Spring authenticaiotn object to get access to
     * current clientId. Adjust accordingly for your own use case
     */
    @Autowired
    private Authentication authentication;

    public JdbcTemplate getTemplate() {
        // TODO - extract this clientId from authenticaiton or any other means as appropriate
        String clientId = null /* write your logic here */;
        return cache.getTemplate(clientId);
    }

}
```

Once above is in place, you must inject `TemplateResolver` instead of injecting `JdbcTempalate` directly in your existing beans. With each existing call to any method of `JdbcTemplate`, replace it with `resolver.getTemplate().existingTemplateCall(...)`

Comment: In our SAAS model, whenever a new client is registered, the DBs would be created using the scripts. So, we would have a master table to map the client ID and DB name. So The client ID would be sent as a parameter to all the APIs, based on that clientID, dynamically the JDBCTemplate needs to be created with the DB of respective clientID. Can the above solution be modified for the mentioned flow?