# Create Multipe Jdbctemplate at runtime pointing to diffrent databases in runtime

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, spring-jdbc, jdbctemplate

Spring boot Is there any way to create **Jdbctemplate at runtime** pointing to the **different MySQL databases**?

Runtime I do have all the required information.

The database structure is the same for all the clients but the instance is different.

I also tried with [How to create multiple Jdbctemplate beans, pointing to different Mysql databases, in runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62909685/how-to-create-multiple-jdbctemplate-beans-pointing-to-different-mysql-databases)
but not able to find any solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess this can be done like this:

```
@Component
public class JdbcTemplateProvider {

    private final Map<String, DataSource> databaseNameToDataSourceMap;
    private final JdbcProperties properties;

    public JdbcTemplateProvider(List<DataSource> dataSources, JdbcProperties properties) {
        this.databaseNameToDataSourceMap = this.buildDatabaseToDataSourceMap(dataSources);
        this.properties = properties;
    }

    public JdbcTemplate byDatabaseName(String database) {
        DataSource dataSource = this.databaseNameToDataSourceMap.get(database);
        return buildJdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    }

    private Map<String, DataSource> buildDatabaseToDataSourceMap(List<DataSource> dataSources) {
        return new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
    }

    private JdbcTemplate buildJdbcTemplate(DataSource dataSource) {
        JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
        JdbcProperties.Template template = properties.getTemplate();
        jdbcTemplate.setFetchSize(template.getFetchSize());
        jdbcTemplate.setMaxRows(template.getMaxRows());
        if (template.getQueryTimeout() != null) {
            jdbcTemplate.setQueryTimeout((int) template.getQueryTimeout().getSeconds());
        }
        return jdbcTemplate;
    }

}
```

If this question was if Spring Boot can natively handle this, as far as I know there may not be any built in solution for this.

`org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.JdbcProperties` reads properties values with prefix `spring.jdbc`.If it is available in your classpath, this will be able to configure newly built `JdbcTemplate` instances as per configuration.

You will have build your own logic though to build map of database name to datasource.

Comment: yes @Paras , there is no in built solution for this, I think this will resolve my issue.

Comment: If it answers your question, kindly consider accepting this answer as well. :)